# Webpack bundle is not exported and can't be imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created my react **Project A** using `Create-React-app`. Then I bundle it them with `Webpack` and saved in my Git account.
Now I create another project(Called it **Project B**)in different directory. Download **Project A** directly from git. And trying to use it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Main } from 'project-A/dist/main'

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am getting an error like following:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The webpack from **Project A** looks like this:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = [
    {
        /*Client Side*/
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename:"./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename:"[id].css"
            })
        ]
    }
]
```

I have research through the github and tried to change the name import, it still does not work.

Project A's component looks like this:

App.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderCodeAuthCard()}
        {this.renderConfirmCard()}
        {this.renderVerifyCard()}
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Apparently webpack is not exporting the bundle file that is created in Project A. Since the import yields "`undefine`".

I am trying to find a way to export my webpack bundle file and use it in another project.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are not exporting any thing from `index.js` of **Project A**. The libraries installed by `npm` export functions from `index.js`.

Comment: but index.js is not a component. It is only responsible for injecting react into HTML page.

Comment: If you need to import a file, it should be exported. You can export component from index of projectA. You cannot import something thats not been exported, so you need to export